# Erlang VM -s Argument is causing my program to fail

Tags: erlang, erl

I have read the thread here: [Erlang VM -s argument misbehaving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080153/erlang-vm-s-argument-misbehaving) and have been troubleshooting to no avail.

When I run the erlang vm without the -s flag, my function works:

```
bridge_sup:start_link().

   Bridge Supervisor Initializing
   [warning] ClientId is NULL!
   [warning] ClientId is NULL!
   Success
   Success
```

However, if I have the -s flag set, when my function goes on to call another function emqttc:start_link(...) it never returns:

```
Bridge Supervisor Initializing
   [warning] ClientId is NULL!
   [warning] ClientId is NULL!
```

I can verify that it is not just a print problem because the program I am connecting to receives no signal.

What could possibly be causing this in the Erlang VM? I have also tried using eval to the same effect. Here is the ./run code:

`erl -pa ebin -pa deps/*/ebin`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would help if you described _exactly_ the sequence of steps that you do when the program works, and correspondingly what you do when it doesn't. There are currently too many unknowns.

Comment: @RichardC please see my answer. I believe the problem is that there was no .app file.

Comment: Yes, but now you are starting the program in a different way, so it could be useful to figure out why it didn't work before. Typically, if it works from the interactive shell, it should work through -s. Is there for example anything that might require the program to be running as a started application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Erlang version 19.2. I am not sure if this is a bug in this version, or it is a requirement to start a program, but I added a .app.src file and added "-eval 'application:start(myprog)'" and the program will now start!

Note that it did not start with -s, -eval, or any of that without the app.src file and without application:start

Answer (score 0):

Could be a startup order problem. Specifying a command to run using -s (or -run or -eval) means that it starts very quickly, while parts of the system may still be starting up in the background. Try adding a sleep at the start of your function and see if it changes anything. In that case, try to figure out what depends on the order.

Comment: just threw in a 1s & 5s wait and it didn't help. I'm running a gen_server and  what it seems like is that none of my handle_info or handle_cast or call functions are being run. For example, I run a connect command, which works, but my gen_server waits for a response in the form of {client, Pid, connected}, State and never gets it. It seems like the message passing is messed up.